# mysql: set default charset to utf8

Tags: mysql, charset

In an effort to set the default charset for a MySQL server to utf8, I've added the following options to `my.ini`

```
character-set-server=utf8
default-collation=utf8_unicode_ci
```

But when I start the mysql client, I get the following error message:

> error: Found option without preceding
>   group in config file:
>   C:\dev\tools\mysql\my.ini at line: 2
>   Fatal error in defaults handling.
>   Program aborted

Does anyone know what the right way to set the default charset in this config file is?

Answer (score 8):

The problem the server complains about is that it can't find the expected INI section (`[mysqld]`) to which these settings belong. Ensure you've added those settings to the `[mysqld]` section, like this:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
default-collation=utf8_unicode_ci
```

If there's already such a section there, add your settings to to that section, don't create a duplicate section.

After altering the configuration file, restart the MySQL server.

Comment: Yeah, what I would call a section (i.e. [mysqld] or [client]) is referred to as a group in MySQL-speak: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: Thanks, wasn't familiar with that terminology :) Me called it like me seen it :)