# how to set mysql to use utf8 by default?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I would like our centOS server 's mysql setup to use utf8 by default.

Can you tell me which file(s) need to be configured and how?

I know it's a pretty vague question but i'm not familiar with server management.
Let me know if you need more details.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At compile time use `--with-charset=utf8` and `--with-collation=utf8_general_ci` options to `configure`.

When creating database or table use `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8`.

It's in the manual! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/61016/install-mysql-client-and-mysql-server-with-default-charset-utf8-to-fedora-11), [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/32228/best-way-to-make-sure-a-mysql-database-is-fully-in-utf8) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/7945/mysql-set-default-charset-to-utf8)...